# All processes using a device got hung and even `kill -9` does nothing

Tags: data-recovery, disk, kill

I have an old HDD which failed and I'm trying to recover what's possible with `testdisk`. The plan was to use `dd` to make an image and then use `testdisk` to recover files from the image to avoid damaging the disk even more.

I used the following command:

```bsh
sudo dd if=/dev/sdc of=/mnt/BigDisk/backup.iso status=progress
```

Everything worked fine until the progress stopped. It didn't go down to 0MB/s it just froze.

I waited for several hours and nothing changed. Then I tryed `Ctrl+C` out of it, but nothing. In the end I sent it a `SIGKILL` (`sudo kill -9 <pid>`) but even this didn't work.
I also tried to run different commands like `lsblk` which also got hung and did not respond to any signal, included `SIGKILL`. In particular, I think that every process that tried to read or get information on that device got frozen and "unkillable".

The last thing I tried was powering-off my PC but, even then, the black screen with the blinking white bar continued to stay there and my PC never turned off.

The following day I tried using `testdisk` directly on `/dev/sdc`. It detected the partition (`ext4`, there was just one of them) correctly and was able to read file names, but when I started copying, after some files happened the same thing it happened to `dd`.

Is this some kind of kernel issue?

System Info:

- OS: `Arch Linux`, Kernel: `5.13.5-arch1-1`
- `/dev/sdc` is an HDD with just one `ext4` partition on a `MBR` partition scheme.
- `/mnt/BigDrive` is an external drive which had one `NTFS` partition on it, which also got damaged and now has a similar behavior as the other disk. It was mounted using `ntfs-3g`.

Comment: Have you also tried `ddrescue`? I have been using that successfully a couple of times. It skips unreadable sectors and should finish eventually.

Comment: @eblock yes, I've also tried it but with the same result

Comment: Could you send a bug report to the kernel? Possibly you have found some places (possibly hardware specific) where the kernel is not handling error path correctly.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi it might, but I have no idea how to do it and I fear to damage my disk even more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I managed to rescue my files.

I may have lied in the question because probably between the moment I tried the first time and when I posted the question I had a kernel update (probably from 5.12 to 5.13). I tried again yesterday with the new kernel and a new hard drive with an ext4 partition as destination and it worked fine. `ddrescue` took something like 12 hours but in the end it finished copying with just a few bites of errors.

Thanks everyone for the advice.